# C# Mono MySql.data writes out nothing

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I have the problem that then I use mysql.data nothing writes out in my console. Not even my console.writeline("hej");

Code:

```
public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("hej");


    string connString = "datasource=localhost;port3306;database=program;uid=joffe;password=hej123;";

    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
    MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tabell";
    try{
        conn.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read()){
            Console.WriteLine(reader["Nick"]);
        }

    conn.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Console image 1]

But if i comment everything after the console.writeline(); the first string is written out.

Everything comment:
[image: Console image 2 working]

Comment: When you set a breakpoint on the `while`, do you reach that line?

Comment: No, not even if i put a breakpoint on line 7.

Comment: What if you single-step from the first line in `Main`? Where does it get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

```
string connString = "Server=localhost;port3306;Database=program;Uid=joffe;Pwd=hej123;";
var sql = "SELECT * FROM tabell";
using(var connection = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read()) Console.WriteLine((string)reader["Nick"]);
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

I've been testing it and found the problem, in your solution you need to copy the reference of the MySql.Data DLL to Local, to do that, open the references folder, click once on MySQL.Data and on the right you will see an icon with a gear on it, click it, then make a local copy of MySql.Data

[image]

Comment: Still nothing is written out on screen.

Comment: Then it must be an issue with the DLL its self, which assembly version do you have, I'm using 6.7.4.0 and everything checks out fine